# App to offline share location

Tags: android, offline, gps

I will start a trip in a couple of days and I would like to have an app in which my friends could see my location for safety reasons.

In most of the places that I will be there is no internet or cell connection, so is there any app that can show my real-time location in a web site or something like that without internet and only GPS?

All apps I can find need internet access to share my location.

It is for Android Samsung S4.

Comment: Without network being available, how should that work? Could only be done "retrospective" once network is available again (hint: GPS is pretty much one-way, receiving only). Apart from that: an app for what? Windows phone? iPhone? Android? Bada? Tizen?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there was a way that people could track me through  gps coordinates or something like that through a site. It is for Android. I dont know much of technologies so maybe somebody knows some other way.

Comment: How? It's your device you want to track, so that's where the GPS receiver is – right? So those coordinates are on a device without network connection. How should that be accessed from elsewhere? Your device has an GPS ***receiver***, not a sender.

Comment: I don't know, that's why Im asking if there is some way. I think if there is a way that an app can see exactly where Im in a map and where I should go offline maybe there is a way that the same or other system can put it in a a site or something... If I knew I wouldnt be asking... So if Im lost in a jungle without internet or cellphone connection I will be the only one knowing where Im?! no body will be able to track me?

Comment: It's about overcoming hardware shortcomings actually, crazy stuff. Don't know if I labelled this right

Comment: I see a lot of close votes on this question, but I thinks it's a perfectly valid one. It's only issue is that the answer is "Such an app does not exist", but that does not make it an invalid question.

Comment: ohh, ok thank you very much for your answer!!! That was just what I wanted to know!!!

Comment: You could do it with extra hardware, eg a satellite phone or SPOT tracker. Some of these can be connected to an Android phone. They would give you coverage just about anywhere in the world (so long as you have a clear view of the sky).

Comment: @vclaw I have taken the liberty of including your good suggestion into my answer, because comments may disappear

Answer (score 4):

Such an app does not exist. You cell phone only has a GPS **receiver** so it cannot communicate anything to the outside world.

Your nearest option would be an app that tracks GPS locations, and whenever it detects internet access, automatically broadcasts (part of) that history. But that would not be real-time, it only logs the last location with internet access where your were present.

Your only real solution seems to be additional hardware (but that's not what you are asking). As [vclaw](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1394/vclaw) suggested in his comment: *You could do it with extra hardware, eg a satellite phone or SPOT tracker. Some of these can be connected to an Android phone. They would give you coverage just about anywhere in the world (so long as you have a clear view of the sky)*

Answer (score 1):

A GPS to SMS app allows your GPS to track your location and *send it via SMS* (GPS transmitter not needed). SMS is more widely available than GPS and generally more reliable in places with poor quality mobile signals.

[GPS Locate and SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_coffeegrainapp.GPS_LocateSMS_Lite) will free, OpenSource and lets you do this.

People can both request your location and receieve messages that you initiate. Conventiently if you do find wifi but don't have a GPS signal there is the option to use the cell network to find your approximate location instead. Often there is a wifi signal but no GPS but this app can manage both.

[GPS Locate and SMS](https://lh3.ggpht.com/uZr4NAN0IcRJRojV2SUcPFFJppthlTEpztUweSz3r2I2Zhh-xPfOE6bJy9P7pf40-8s=h310-rw)

**Features list from play store**

- Functionality:
  The basic and main point of this application is: to locate your position. If you have access to the Internet, you can get the location address. You can send your location to another user, or receive the location of another user. You can use the application to navigate to there. And receive an automatic answer to inquiry of your location.
  You can choose between GPS or Network. This can be very useful when there is no GPS signal. Accuracy is also displayed. Internet is used to get current location address and online map when using google maps.
- SHARE your location to predefined number, with short comment.
- STORE three locations: You can use one as a GoHome Location and two more for other use.
  Use Google Maps to navigate or show your current position. If you have downloaded maps of your planned location, it also works off line.
- RECEIVE location of another user, through received SMS. Receive SMS from another user and instantly record their position and get distance to given coordinates!
- SEND your location through SMS
- ANSWER for asked location with SMS.
  IMPORTANT Application records received messages even if the application is not running, so when you receive a GPS Locate & SMS message it is stored in the application. App stores only the last received location!
- COMPASS, simple compass, just to help you navigate.
- TRACK, simple way to track received location. Your tracked location is in the middle of the screen and it shows in what direction you should go.

Another option is **GPS to SMS by Tralchonok Labs** also free.

Limtations are that SMS needs to be initiated manually and sends to one number by default, but a scheduling app like Tasker could send an hourly or twice per day SMS, and SMS could be used to update social media with your location,  eg Four Square or Linked In. Anyone who does not get the SMS can request your location by SMS and you just hit Answer.  Using SMS to send an email is another option, with some e-mail companies allowing SMS for 'posting' emails. SMS just sits there until you next have a network connection then sends which is handy.